# Proof verification: Application of optional stopping theorem

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

I am wondering if the proof of this equation below using the optional stopping theorem is correct.

$\textbf{Proposition}$
Let $\tau : \omega \mapsto \{1,2,\dots,\infty\}$ be a stopping time w.r.t a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t=1,2,\dots}$.

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots$ be a collection of integrable random variables ($\mathbb{E}[|x_i|] < \infty$ for all $i$).

Further suppose that there is a finite $c$ such that $\tau \leq c$ with probability $1$.

Then
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\tau}x_i\right] = 
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\tau}\mathbb{E}\left[x_i \mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right]\right].
\end{equation}

$\textbf{Proof idea}$

1. Define 
   $S_1 = x_1 - \mathbb{E}[x_1]$
   and for $n>1$ set 
   $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_i \mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}])$.
2. Then $S_n$ is a martingale w.r.t $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t=1,2,\dots}$
3. Since it is also true that $\tau$ is bounded w.p.1, the optional sampling theorem applies and $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau}] = \mathbb{E}[S_1] = 0$, which is exactly equivalent to Equation $1$.

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: @saz is it a little weird that it involves $\mathcal{F}_{1-1} = \mathcal{F}_{0}$ , which hasn't been defined? Should the statement define $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ to be the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, or something?

Comment: Yeah, it's the trivial one. (By the way, there is a typo in the definition of $S_1$, clearly the (two) $i$'s have to replaced by $1$'s.)

Comment: @saz I wanted to share this other question in case you may have some insight to contribute: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228625/quadratic-martingale-bound)