# Quadratic martingale bound

Tags: probability-theory, summation, martingales

Let
$a_1,a_2,\dots$
be random variables that are adapted to the filtration
{$\mathcal{F}_{t}$ } such that 
$$\mathbb{E}[a_i \mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}] \leq K$$ for all $i$.
Then for any stopping time $\tau$, we have that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\tau}a_i\right] \leq \mathbb{E}[\tau] K.
$$
See for instance the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3007157/119483).

Now suppose that the $a_i$ satisfy a growth bound:
$$\mathbb{E}[a_{i} \mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}] \leq a_{i-1} + K.$$
Intuitively, I want to reason that 
$a_i \approx i K$, and therefore
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\tau}a_i\right] \leq \mathbb{E}[\tau^2] K.$$
Is there a way to formally establish this inequality, or is there some reason why it would not hold?